# Fundamentals of Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have two boxes , containing white and black balls. In the first one , we have 8 white and 6 black balls. In the second one , we have 4 white and 7 black balls.

Now if one ball is drawn at random , suppose we need to find the probability o it being black.

Now by the classical definition : there are 7 + 6 ways in which we can select a single black ball.

And the total number of ways in which we can select a single ball is 14 + 11 = 25

So the probability using this approach is 13/25

However , if we break the problem up into two parts , the probability of selecting a particular box , and then selecting a single ball , we get

(1/2* 6/14) + (1/2*7/11)

These two approaches lead to different answers.

I'd like to know why the first one is incorrect

Thanks!

Comment: a) What is "the classical definition"? b) In this situation, what do you mean by "drawing a ball at random"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on whether you give equal weighting to a box, or to a ball - the question is not well framed. What does it mean to choose a ball "at random" in this case?

Your "classical" approach is valid if choosing a ball at random means "each ball has equal probability of being picked", more or less ignoring the boxes.

Your second approach is valid if choosing a ball at random means selecting one of the boxes at probability 0.5 each, and only then choosing a ball (each with equal probabilities) from within that box.

The two interpretations of "pick a ball at random" lead to different answers.

This may be made more obvious by considering the following more extreme example: the first box contains 99 white balls, the second contains a single black ball. What is the probability of choosing a black ball? Answer: it depends on your method of choosing a ball "at random", ie whether you assign equal probabilities to boxes, or to balls.

Comment: I have some doubts that this will do much to clear up the OP's confusion. The main problem in the question, to my mind, is that it seems to assume that "drawing a ball at random" is a self-evident, well-defined concept which suffices to specify the problem and lead to a single correct answer (with a different answer being labeled "incorrect"). Your expression "giving equal weightings to boxes" doesn't make it very clear (to me) that the problem lies in the definition of the random experiment; it sounds as if it might refer to the method of calculation.

Comment: @joriki Edited - please can you let me know if this looks better?

Comment: Much better -- very clear now, +1!

Answer (score 0):

Once you say that there are two **boxes**, you obviously can draw a ball from only one box, so lumping together all the balls as if there were no boxes is incorrect.

Assuming that each box has equal probability of being picked, the 2nd approach is correct.

Comment: This is exactly my question. It might seem incorrect probability wise. However, if you count the number of favorable events (as required) - we still see that there are   13 favorable events.

Apologies - if I'm missing out something too obvious . In that case kindly point it out

Comment: Choosing a black ball from box 1 is a separate event from choosing a black ball from box 2, and it is an OR type of situation, that is why you compute P(black ball from box 1) + P(black ball from box 2) = $(\frac12\cdot\frac{6}{14}) + (\frac12\cdot\frac{7}{11})$

Comment: @Anant: Dividing the number of favourable events by the total number of events yields the probability if all those events are equally likely. If by "draw a ball at random" you mean "pick a box uniformly at random, then pick a ball from that box uniformly at random", then there's no reason to expect each of the events you defined to be equally likely, and hence no reason for the probability to be given by the ratio of favourable to total events. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference.